# what hit fertile ground mean?

Tags: meaning

> “We had to find a way to break down the silos and introduce a platform that allows staff in 28 countries to
>   better communicate and collaborate. [With our Jive-n Social Intranet] we really **hit fertile ground**. We had a
>   97% adoption rate in four months. The platform is extremely secure; it’s essentially a **vault beneath the desk**.”

i have problem in meaning of vault beneath the desk and hit fertile ground.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"hit fertile ground" means it has tremendous growth potential (same as a plant growing in fertile soil).

A similar phrase is "hit paydirt" (from gold prospecting days).

I suppose in "vault beneath the desk", *vault* means a container (or vault) full of money, and *beneath the desk* is the location of the system running the "Jive-n Social Intranet".
So the "Jive-n Social Intranet" will make as much money as you want.